# Forcing SQL result to to fill in missing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the one below:

```
timeUnit    country    name    count
    1          UK      Fred     12
    1          GE      Bob      1
    1          GE      John     3
    2          UK      Fred     6
    2          GE      Bob      5
    2          GE      John     8
    3          UK      Fred     4
    3          GE      Bob      6
    3          GE      John     5
    4          UK      Fred     4
    4          GE      Bob      8
    4          GE      John     9
    4          UK      Philip   6
    5          UK      Fred     3
    5          GE      Bob      2
    5          GE      John     1
    5          UK      Philip   5
    6          UK      Fred     8
    6          GE      Bob      9
    7          UK      Fred     8
    7          GE      Bob      9
    7          GE      John     8
    7          UK      Philip   6
    8          UK      Fred     5
    8          GE      Bob      1
    8          GE      John     1
```

What I want to do is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE country ='UK'
```

But have the result include missing timeUnit results for Philip with counts of zero, i.e. return:

```
timeUnit    country    name    count
   1           UK      Fred      12
   1           UK      Philip    0
   2           UK      Fred      6
   2           UK      Philip    0
   3           UK      Fred      4
   3           UK      Philip    0
etc...
```

I have a feeling this should be possible with some form of join on a temp table or query but really struggling to get my head around it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do the names also exist in another table or just in this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `timeUnit`, `name` values are comprehensively included in your table, you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.timeUnit, 
       COALESCE(t3.country, 'UK') AS country, 
       t2.name,  
       COALESCE(SUM(count), 0) AS count
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT timeUnit
   FROM Table1) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT name
   FROM Table1
   WHERE country = 'UK') AS t2
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT timeUnit, country, name, count
   FROM Table1
   WHERE country = 'UK'
) AS t3 ON t1.timeUnit = t3.timeUnit AND t2.name = t3.name
GROUP BY t1.timeUnit, t3.country, t2.name
ORDER BY t1.timeUnit, t2.name
```

`CROSS JOIN` is used to create an in-line table containing all possible (`timeUnit`, `name`) pairs for the case where `country = 'UK'`. Performing a `LEFT JOIN` to this table gives a result set containing all possible (`timeUnit`, `name`) pairs along with the corresponding count.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9f22/1)

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Had not come across cross joins before.

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` coluimn is the only source of names, you can perform a subquery to get all the distinct names from the table and then `LEFT JOIN` the results of the subquery to the main table, using aggregation to get the values you are looking for.

```
SELECT
    t.timeUnit AS timeUnit,
    t.country AS country,
    names.name AS name,
    SUM(t.`count`) AS `count`
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table1
) AS names
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t
    ON names.name = t.name
WHERE country = ?
GROUP BY timeUnit, name
```

Comment: No, you do not need to refer to such a column name using backticks all the time. Tablename.fieldname format is also acceptable and no need for backticks that time. But I agree, reserved words should not be used  as field names.

Comment: @Shadow You are correct that in this example `table.field` format would be enough for MySQL to not have a problem with an ambiguous field definition.  Since many don't use `table.field` format unless their is a join involved, this could be problematic.  I have updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: COUNT is not a reserved word (it's not even classed as a keyword!) But that's not to say that I'd advocate its use a table/column identifier!

Comment: @Strawberry I stand corrected. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html